# Android menu estilo bullet em item de RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Antes de mais nada já tenho um conhecimento intermediário sobre o android e já tenho alguns aplicativos no google play.

Recentemente estive atualizando o layout do meu aplicativo, eu tenho uma galeria de vídeos no meu app que sempre que for preciso deletar um item ou ver  as informações eu usava um ContextMenu, mas agora eu substituir o ListView por um RecyclerView e queria mostrar o menu de uma maneira diferente, gostaria de adicionar um botão de menu semelhante ao botão de que aparece na toolbar quando se infla um menu (Imagem a seguir). O problema é que não consigo descobrir como se chama aquele botão, provavelmente não é um ícone adicionado em um image button com o fundo transparente pois isso parece ser um widget nativo do android e pude notar que já estava presente até nas verões antigas do android.

[image: Botão em questão]

Me refiro ao botão direito, o esquerdo já sei que se chama hamburguer

[image: Botão que me refiro na toolbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome do icon é **"more vert"**.

Ele pode ser obtido, no Android Studio, através do Image Asset / Vector Asset.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, perdi muito tempo procurando este botão e o mais próximo que achei da resposta foi bullet icon